# fourier transform for pde equation

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I was solving the pde using fourier transform: $u_{tt}-u_{xx}+m^2u=0$ with initial values $u(0,x)=f(x)$ and $u_t(0,x)=g(x)$.

I have received the answer $$U(t,k)=Ae^{-it \sqrt {k^2+m^2}}+Be^{it \sqrt {k^2+m^2}}$$
where $A, B, m$ are constants, and $U(t,k)$ is the Fourier transform of $u(t,x)$.
Now I have problems with turning $U$ to $u$. I tried to do it directly, calculating the integral for inverse fourier, but I got stuck since the integral contains $e^{it \sqrt{k^2+m^2}+ikx}dk$ and $f(x)$, $g(x)$ a bit different from that.

Can someone help me, please?

Any hints are welcome!

Thank you!

Comment: Let 
$$u_{tt}-u_{xx}+m^2u=0\tag{0}$$
$$u(x,t)\rightarrow \hat{u}(k,t)\tag{1}$$
$$u_{xx}\rightarrow -k^2\hat{u}(k,t)\tag{2}$$
$$u_{tt}\rightarrow \frac{\partial^2 \hat{u}(k,t)}{\partial t^2}\tag{3}$$
Using 1-3 in (0), we have
$$-\frac{\partial^2\hat{u}(k,t)}{\partial t^2}=k^2\hat{u}(k,t)+m^2\hat{u}(k,t)=\hat{u}(k,t)(k^2+m^2)$$
$$\Rightarrow \hat{u}(k,t)=Ae^{-it \sqrt {k^2+m^2}}+Be^{it \sqrt {k^2+m^2}}\tag{4}$$
Now, applying the initial conditions given
$$\hat{u}(k,0)=A+B=f(k)\tag{5}$$
$$\hat{u}_t(k,0)=-i\sqrt{k^2+m^2}A+i\sqrt{k^2+m^2}B=g(k)\tag{6}$$

How did you proceed from (6)?

Comment: it was long time ago, but thanks for the answer! However, using the last two equations we can get the value of $A$ and $B$, and we can put them back into (4). But how would we do inverse Fourier transform to get $u(t,x)$?

Comment: Actually, I was trying to organize the solution to check if there was something missing. So, $A=1$ and $B=0$ right? That would get us to problematic integral
$$u(x,t)=\int e^{it \sqrt{k^2+m^2}+ikx}dk$$
I'll take this problem to a math-physics Phd. I'm really curious about it. Hope to have some progress soon.

Comment: @LinconRibeiro Any progress?

Comment: Hi @ViktorStein , sorry for taking so long on this, but I haven't had the time to take this question to the person I mentioned and I left college a few years ago. I will try to contact someone else on the next days. Let's see. In the meantime, try chatting with this guy here: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/118056/ivo-terek